# Encode a graph using a three-character language?

Tags: string, graph, graph-algorithm, representation

Suppose you have an alphabet with only three characters, say, `0, 1, @`.  How can you represent an unweighted (all vertices and edges have the weight 1), undirected graph `G = (V, E)` using only a string of these characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try an adjacency matrix.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

maybe use the @ to represent each new line.

so 100@010@001@ would be the identity matrix

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that myself.

Comment: pretty cool concept. just out of curiosity why are you limited to 3 chars?

Comment: I want to be able to store it in a plain-text format in a way that is easy for end users to read and edit with a text editor like Notepad.

Comment: then using the new line as one of the characters seems like a logical choice! It'll let the user see the matrix the way it should be written.

Comment: Good idea.  I'll do that instead.